# angularjs - calculate a date plus one day

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I need to get the date one day after another date.
I do :

```
$scope.date2.setDate($scope.date1.getDate()+1);

if   
$scope.date1 = 2015-11-27  

then 
$scope.date2 = 2015-11-28

It s ok,
but when 

$scope.date1 = 2015-12-02

 then 
 $scope.date2 = 2015-11-28 (ie tomorrow)
```

I don't understand why...

If anyone knows..

Comment: why don't you try javascript Date function and add days to it  `addDays(1)` rather doing `+1`

Comment: also i will suggest you to create JsFiddle or Stack's inbuilt snippet creator, so people can see the actual problem and provide better solution

Comment: I don't see any addDays in Javascript

Comment: you can use moment.js for date calculations

Comment: I believe @supercool is referring to custom function like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime cmiiw

Comment: `getDate()` gets the date for today. If you increment it, it will be tomorrow. Everything works as it is supposed. Your logic inside the code is wrong.

Comment: getDate() gives the day number in the month : 2. not the date, I don't understand why. I ve came up with one solution : $scope.date2=new Date($scope.date1.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Comment: this can be a cause of problem for leap year calculation

Answer (score 3):

try this instead **efficient** **simple** **pure JS**

```
var todayDate = new Date();    
console.log(new Date().setDate(todayDate.getDate()+1));
```

so you will have that same `Date` type  object and hence you don't need to go with `moment.js`

Answer (score 2):

Use moment.js for this [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs)

```
var startdate = "2015-12-02";
var new_date = moment(startdate, "YYYY-MM-DD").add('days', 1);
var day = new_date.format('DD');
var month = new_date.format('MM');
var year = new_date.format('YYYY');
alert(new_date);
alert(day + '.' + month + '.' + year);
```